# jdbc / PreparedStatement escape sequence

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to implement jdbc escape sequence while calling a SQL via PreparedStatement in Java.

Below is my sample code.

```
String sql ="select 1 from dual where  'abcd' = ? {escape '|'}";
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,"abcd");
ps.executeQuery();
```

While executing the class I'm getting the below error.

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jdbcdslog.PreparedStatementLoggingHandler.invoke(PreparedStatementLoggingHandler.java:35)
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

The [escape sequence you mention](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13157_01/wlevs/docs30/jdbc_drivers/sqlescape.html#wp1056653) is only valid with `LIKE` clauses.

Try the following instead:

```
String sql = "select 1 from dual where 'abcd' like ? {escape '|'}";
```

Comment: can't use escape sequence with IN clause?

Comment: @Gopal: no.  Only with a `LIKE` clause.  Why would you want to use it with an `IN` clause?

Comment: I have a number of sql files within which there are IN clauses that will accept variable number of arguments. I thought of escaping the single quote and pass a single String from Java to sql. 

Something like
ps.setString(1, "abc|', |'bcd|'");

and escape the | (pipe) symbol.

Comment: @Gopal How would that even work, don't think that you can invent features that a database doesn't have.